# Google Maps: Set Center, Set Center Point and Set more points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps V3 and I want to:

1. Set the center of the map to a particular latlng. I am using:

   ```
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mylat,mylong));
   ```
2. Set a point in that center spot. I am currently using:

   ```
   var point = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat,mylong);

   marker = map_create_marker(point,"My Popup",map_icon_red);
   ```

   With this function:

   ```
   function map_create_marker(point,html,icon) {
       var marker =    new google.maps.Marker({
           position: point,
           map: map,
           icon: icon,
           shadow: map_icon_shadow
       });

       if(html!="") {
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   content: html
           });
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               infowindow.open(map,marker);
           });
       }
       return marker;
   }
   ```
3. Position many more markers using the same method above

The problem is that when I set the center like above, it only ever displays the first marker. But if I don't set a center it displays all the markers. How can I get them to both work?

Here is the full javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var map;

    var map_icon_green = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/green_pointer.png",
        new google.maps.Size(12,20),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));

    var map_icon_blue = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/blue_pointer.png",
        new google.maps.Size(12,20),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));

    var map_icon_yellow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/yellow_pointer.png",
        new google.maps.Size(12,20),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));

    var map_icon_red = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/red_pointer.png",
        new google.maps.Size(12,20),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));

    var map_icon_shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/shadow.png",
        new google.maps.Size(28,20),
        new google.maps.Point(-6,0));

    var map_crosshair = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://mysite.com/cross-hair.gif",
        new google.maps.Size(17,17),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));


    function map_loader() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel:false
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map_container'), myOptions);

        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.0,-1.0));

        // <![CDATA[
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(53.0,-4.0755);
        marker = map_create_marker(point,"some html which is OK",map_icon_red);
        // ]]>

        // <![CDATA[
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.0,25.0);
        marker = map_create_marker(point,"some html which is OK",map_icon_red);
        // ]]>

        // <![CDATA[
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(54.0,-2.0);
        marker = map_create_marker(point,"some html which is OK",map_icon_red);
        // ]]>

        map.disableDoubleClickZoom = false;
    }


    function map_create_marker(point,html,icon) {
        var marker =    new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            shadow: map_icon_shadow
        });

        if(html!="") {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }
        return marker;
    }
    var map_set_center = 0;
    function map_load_resize() {
        if(map_set_center==0) {
             map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.0,-1.0));
        }
        map_set_center = 1;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: did you zoom out to see if other markers are also displayed when you setCenter?

Comment: yes, and no other markers are displayed. I have also checked to ensure the HTML for the markers are throwing the error, they aren't.

Comment: @David can you post the entirety of your code prefer with generic marker data like mylat and mylong

Comment: seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/VzheV/ granted i commented out icon image and shadow.

Comment: The icons are sort of the whole point.

Comment: @David link direct links to your icons and shadow please if it is important and may contribute to your issue.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try using this code for v3:

```
gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')); 
gMap.setZoom(13);      // This will trigger a zoom_changed on the map
gMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));
gMap.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the API has changed and `setCenter` is no longer valid :(

Answer (score 1):

The use of `google.maps.LatLng` is not necessary anymore. The code below should work,

```
map.setCenter({ lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629 });
```