# Default center on United States?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

By default, google offers this example of how to center a map on Chicago, IL:

```
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
```

Is it possible to have the default center focus on the entire United States? I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: @KenWhite I'll accept that as an answer if you make it one

Comment: Done, with credit given to the original answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Chicago as the center, and then change the `zoom`.

There's an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663492/62576). A slightly reworked version (untested!):

```
gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')); 
gMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523));
gMap.setZoom(ANewZoomLevel);
```

You'll need to experiment to find the right zoom level for your needs.

Comment: This makes sense, but using the viewport as geocodezip suggest is even better :)

Comment: The geographic center of the contiguous United States is the center of 48 U.S. states. It has been regarded as such by the U.S. National Geodetic Survey (NGS) since the 1912 additions of New Mexico and Arizona to the United States.

Comment: more accurate would be Lebanon, KS: [39.809734, -98.555620]

Answer (score 25):

Use the Geographic Center of the Contiguous United States:
Lebanon, Kansas. Probably the most boring place on earth.

http://www.kansastravel.org/geographicalcenter.htm

I find that a **zoom of 3, 4, or 5** is perfect.

```
gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')); 
gMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.8097343, -98.5556199));
gMap.setZoom(3);
```

Answer (score 10):

Since it's the entire United States, it seems silly to get into decimals with the LatLng. I like:

```
new google.maps.Map($map, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39, -95),
    zoom: 3
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/AQpwW/)

Comment: @TalasanNicholson It does, jsfiddle example added to prove it.

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use the geocoder.  If you [geocode "United States of America"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=United%20States%20of%20America&geocode=1),  it returns a "suggested viewport", which can be used to center and zoom the map:

```
"viewport": {
  "Z": {
    "b": 25.82,
    "d": 49.38
  },
  "ca": {
    "b": -124.38999999999999,
    "d": -66.94
  }
}
```

The center/location the geocoder returns is: `37.09024, -95.712891`

translates to:

```
"viewport": {
  NorthEast: { lat:49.38, lng:-66.94 },
  SouthWest: { lat:25.82, lng:-124.39 }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74p6041g/)

There are two similar pieces of information, the bounds and the suggested viewport.  I believe the bounds includes Alaska and Hawaii, the viewport might suit your needs better.

The simplest way is to manually center the map and zoom it how you like it then get the current values using getCenter() and getZoom() then use those to initialize the map.

Here is an [example that uses the geocode to zoom to countries from a drop down list](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html), (it uses the bounds, rather than the viewport, which for the US are different)

Answer (score 5):

Fit bounds works best, because zoom depends on device width. What looks good on one device is too big or too small for another device. Hence:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.82, -124.39),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.38, -66.94)
);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Chicago isn't very flexible.  Take points at the extreme cardinals of the united states, essentially creating a bounding box, then add them to a bounds object and use that to fit your bounds and zoom on the map:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(24.891752, -98.4375));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(40.351289, -124.244385));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(44.488196, -70.290656));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(49.000282, -101.37085));
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

This will fit your map regardless of the size of the canvas.