# Laravel- farhanwazir laravelgooglemaps

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

I am trying to add a google maps view but it doesn't seem to recognise where I want it to show. This is my current output.. just showing what appears to be the sea?
[image]

//route

```
Route::get('googlemap', 'MapController@map');
```

//controller

```
public function map() {


$config['center'] = 'Sydney Airport,Sydney';
$config['zoom'] = '14';
  $config['map_height'] = '400px';

  $gmap = new GMaps();
  $gmap->initialize($config);

  $map = $gmap->create_map();
  return view('map',compact('map')); }
```

//view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Laravel Google Maps Example</title>
    {!! $map['js'] !!}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        {!! $map['html'] !!}
</div></body></html>
```

I have my config file set up and I have added my google API key..

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: So the map works but not centered on anything, what if you zoom out. Also please check this for setting lat/long https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663492/10634638

Comment: if i zoom out it is always displaying from north Atlantic sea.. & thanks will take a look now

Answer (score 0):

Use the latitude and longitude values instead of the name of the location. e.g to center the map to Kampala, Uganda I used this

```
$config['center'] = '0.347596, 32.582520';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late but I will tell you my solution in case another needs it.

The solution was to add the key in a certain line of code in the GMaps.php file:

This is how it was at the beginning:

```
$data_location = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode(utf8_encode($address))."&sensor=".$this->sensor;
```

This is how it has to be:

```
$data_location = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode(utf8_encode($address))."&sensor=".$this->sensor."&key=".$this->apiKey;
```